# this.async() in yeoman-generator

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, yeoman-generator

I am learning how to write a yeoman-generator. I have a question regarding the code below. It says by adding `var done = this.async();` and call the method later in callback, we can make the function `askFor()` a asynchronized function. Could someone please explain why?

```
askFor: function() {
    var done = this.async();

    // Have Yeoman greet the user.
    this.log(yosay('Welcome to the marvelous Myblog generator!'));

    var prompts = [{
        name: 'blogName',
        message: 'What do you want to call your blog?',
        default: 'myblog'
    }];

    this.prompt(prompts, function(props) {
        this.blogName = props.blogName;

        done();
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Here is the code of `this.async`

```
this.async = function() {
    return function() {};
}
```

Comment: Do you already understand the difference between synchronous and asynchronous javascript?

Comment: Yes, I do understand the difference. But I don't understand how it makes the code asynchronous here by using `this.async()`

Answer (score 8):

Just fell on this question by pure coincidence searching for something else.

Actually, `this.async` is overwritten on each method during the `run` phase to either delay execution until completion or run synchronously.

You can read the relevant code line here: 
https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/base.js#L372-L393

So basically, behind the scenes Yeoman always call a callback. When you call `this.async()` we keep a reference variable and return the callback. If you don't call it, we take care of calling the callback manually after the function end.